# I have two dataframes (DF1) and (DF2). I want to substitute values for a column in (DF2) that match criteria on two columns of (DF1)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to populate the 'Salary' column in DataFrame1 (DF1) with the corresponding 'Salary' in DataFrame2 (DF2). These need to match on 'Team' AND 'Players'.

To note:

The Dataframes are:
Not the same size.
Not the same order.

```
import pandas as pd


#df 1:

nba_data = {'Team': ['Mavericks', 'Mavericks', 'Mavericks', '', 'NewYorkKnicks17','Houston Rockets', 'NewYorkKnicks17'], 
            'Players': ['Luka Doncic', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'Jalen Brunson', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'JR Smith',
                        'James Harden', 'Derrick Rose',],
            'Salary': ['0', '0', '0','0', '0', '0', '0'],
           'Coach': ['Rick Carlisle', 'Rick Carlisle', 'Steve Kerr', 'Phil Jackson', 'Tom Thibideou', '', '']}

nba_df1 = pd.DataFrame(nba_data)

nba_df1


#df2:

nba_data2 = {'Team': ['Mavericks', 'Mavericks', 'Mavericks', 'NewYorkKnicks17', 'NewYorkKnicks17', 'NewYorkKnicks17', 'Houston Rockets'], 
            'Players': ['Luka Doncic', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'Steph Curry', 'JR Smith', 'Derrick Rose',
                        'Kristaps Porzingis', 'James Harden'],
            'Salary': ['3m', '126m', '0','115m', '0', '20m', '1.5m'],
            'Coach': ['Rick Carlisle', 'Rick Carlisle', 'Steve Kerr', '', 'Tom Thibideou', 'Phil Jackson', '']}


nba_df2 = pd.DataFrame(nba_data2)

nba_df2
```

Result desired = nba_df1 with the appropriate salaries populated (run the below):

```
nba_data3 = {'Team': ['Mavericks', 'Mavericks', 'Mavericks', '', 'NewYorkKnicks17','Houston Rockets', 'NewYorkKnicks17'], 
            'Players': ['Luka Doncic', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'Jalen Brunson', 'Kristaps Porzingis', 'JR Smith',
                        'James Harden', 'Derrick Rose',],
            'Salary': ['3m', '126m', '0','20m', '115m', '1.5m', '0'],
           'Coach': ['Rick Carlisle', 'Rick Carlisle', 'Steve Kerr', 'Phil Jackson', 'Tom Thibideou', '', '']}



nba_df1_adjusted = pd.DataFrame(nba_data3)






Kindly note: this is not a tutorial. - it is a specific question and therefore not a duplicate of a general tutorial.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: This is specific - that is a tutorial of some sort? @baccandr

Comment: That is a great QnA post, just go through it and you will be able to easily solve your problem!

Comment: Looks like a good post, but it is incorrect to say this is a duplicate. The same could be said of if you linked a google search to a book and said if you just go through this you can solve your problem. I also didn't see any OR condition in that post - so it won't solve my problem seemingly. @baccandr thanks for linking though - may come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
agg = pd.merge(nba_df1, nba_df2, on = ['Players', 'Team'], how = 'left')
```

Your result will be on Salary_y

Edit:
Kind of dirty but it works:

```
agg = pd.merge(nba_df1, nba_df2[['Team', 'Players', 'Salary']], on = ['Players', 'Team'], how = 'left')
agg2 = pd.merge(nba_df1, nba_df2, on = ['Players', 'Coach'], how = 'left')

merge = pd.merge(agg, agg2, on = ['Players', 'Coach'])

merge['Salary'] = merge['Salary_y_x'].fillna(merge['Salary_y_y'])
```

Comment: Hi @Hamza, this leaves the 3rd row Salary_Y blank. Somewhere in here I need it to match on ['Players', 'Team] OR ['Players, 'Coach'] when there is no 'Team' as in row 3. If possible are you able to amend your answer? Many thanks

Comment: Why not just join on 'Player' then: ? `agg = pd.merge(nba_df1, nba_df2, on = ['Players''], how = 'left')`

Comment: Because the data for a player ie: 'Kristaps Porzingis'. Is not the same for each team he has been a part of. ie: Row 1 (Mavericks | Kristaps Porzingis - salary = 126m). Whereas Row 3 (' ' | Kristaps Porzingis | Phil Jackson - salary = 20m).

Comment: Editted my answer hope it helps